# Bitmapped indexes not enabled in Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, indexing, bitmap-index

I am using Oracle 10g XE (express edition).  If I try to create a bitmap index, I get an error

**ORA-00439 feature not enabled: Bit mapped Indexes**

How do I solve this problem and create a bitmap index?

Comment: Which edition of 10g? I believe bitmap indexes are only available in Enterprise Edition, but don't have a reference for that to hand.

Comment: @AlexPoole I am using Express Edition

Comment: Please can you tell me the solution...

Comment: The solution is simple - send money to Oracle.  Bitmapped indexes are Enterprise only, at least in 10g.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The online documentation includes a Licensing guide.  This says:

```
Feature                                |  Availability
---------------------------------------+--------------
Bitmapped index, bitmapped join index  |  No
```

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/license.102/b25456/toc.htm#BABJBGGA).

The point being, Express Edition is free and consequently doesn't come with all the features of Oracle's paid for databases.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see the status of the bitmap feature by using the following query:

```
select * from V$OPTION WHERE PARAMETER = 'Bit-mapped indexes';


PARAMETER                                   VALUE                    CON_ID
------------------------------------------- ------------------------ ----------
Bit-mapped indexes                          TRUE                      0
```

I just checked the documentation because I run into the same error. Depending on the edition this feature is anabled or not:

- Express Edition: FALSE
- Standard Edition: FALSE
- Enterprise Edition: TRUE